# I want to open a jupyter notebook (.ipynb) file in an editor with Javascript /React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I want to open a jupyter notebook (.ipynb) file in an editor with Javascript /React,

i found a library react-jupyter-notebook , this opens the file but dont let me edit the code .

Does anyone know a library/node module that let me open and edit the notebook in Javascript or React.

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of the `react-jupyter-notebook`. As far as I know, there is no library in javascript/react that can edit a notebook file out of the box.

I do have the plan to update `react-jupyter-notebook` so that it can also edit the notebooks (only editing functionality, no way to execute the code). The difficulty lies in the fact that even a very basic text editor needs to implement lots of functionalities to be usable. Fortunately, I already have a plan on how to do this and hopefully, I can get it done within months.